# Output plot of result to genetic algorithm on knapsack doesn't show

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

You are going to spend a month in the wilderness. You’re taking a backpack with you, however, the maximum weight it can carry is 20 kilograms. You have a number of survival items available, each with its own number of “survival points”. You’re objective is to maximize the number of survival points.

```
item    survivalpoints  weight
pocketknife     10.00   1.00
beans   20.00   5.00
potatoes    15.00   10.00
unions  2.00    1.00
sleeping bag    30.00   7.00
rope    10.00   5.00
compass     30.00   1.00
```

**This is my objective**

while am executing it is not showing the output

```
library(genalg)
library(ggplot2)
library(animation)
dataset <- data.frame(item = c("pocketknife", "beans", "potatoes", "unions", 
                               "sleeping bag", "rope", "compass"), survivalpoints = c(10, 20, 15, 2, 30, 
                                                                                      10, 30), weight = c(1, 5, 10, 1, 7, 5, 1))
weightlimit <- 20
chromosome = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
dataset[chromosome == 1, ]
cat(chromosome %*% dataset$survivalpoints)
evalFunc <- function(x) {
  current_solution_survivalpoints <- x %*% dataset$survivalpoints
  current_solution_weight <- x %*% dataset$weight

  if (current_solution_weight > weightlimit) 
    return(0) else return(-current_solution_survivalpoints)
}



iter = 100
GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size = 7, popSize = 200, iters = iter, mutationChance = 0.01, 
                    elitism = T, evalFunc = evalFunc)
cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel))


solution = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
dataset[solution == 1, ]

cat(paste(solution %*% dataset$survivalpoints, "/", sum(dataset$survivalpoints)))
animate_plot <- function(x) {
  for (i in seq(1, iter)) {
    temp <- data.frame(Generation = c(seq(1, i), seq(1, i)), Variable = c(rep("mean", 
                                                                              i), rep("best", i)), Survivalpoints = c(-GAmodel$mean[1:i], -GAmodel$best[1:i]))

    pl <- ggplot(temp, aes(x = Generation, y = Survivalpoints, group = Variable, 
                           colour = Variable)) + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 
                                                                                             iter)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 110)) + geom_hline(y = max(temp$Survivalpoints), 
                                                                                                                                                          lty = 2) + annotate("text", x = 1, y = max(temp$Survivalpoints) + 
                                                                                                                                                                                2, hjust = 0, size = 3, color = "black", label = paste("Best solution:", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       max(temp$Survivalpoints))) + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
      opts(title = "Evolution Knapsack optimization model")

    print(pl)
saveMovie(animate_plot(), interval = 0.1, outdir = getwd())

  }}
```

Comment: your code seems to be an exact copy of [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/)...